# How to make a div scrollable inside a div and make the outside div become blurred

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div, 1 is for the container and 1 is for the content, but I want to make the container/div that colored yellow to show the content and blurred.

[image]

so far I have done this but still not working.

```css
/* Apply styles to the container div */
.frame {
    height: 400px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
    margin: 50px auto;
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scrolling for the content */
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.frame::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Create the blurred frame using ::before and ::after pseudo-elements */
.frame::before,
.frame::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners for the frame */
    background: #ecab7a;
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}

/* Style the content inside the frame */
.content {
    padding: 20px; /* Add padding to ensure content is not obscured by the frame */
    background-color: #29367d; /* Blue background color for content */
    color: white; /* Text color for content */
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Welcome to the Blurred Frame</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam accumsan diam nec ex sodales vehicula. Vivamus eu rhoncus mi. Vestibulum a nisi ut dolor blandit hendrerit. Sed auctor magna nec tristique. Fusce aliquam felis non ipsum fringilla, et venenatis sem hendrerit. Praesent id congue odio. Proin tincidunt urna et quam consequat fringilla. Curabitur malesuada quam vel elit posuere, ac consectetur quam ultricies. Donec vel est vel nisi consectetur fermentum. Phasellus ullamcorper, sapien nec semper gravida, lorem arcu tincidunt libero, et consectetur tortor purus non arcu.</p>
        <p>Integer bibendum felis vel urna scelerisque, non vestibulum velit pellentesque. Phasellus posuere augue quis orci dignissim, sed tempus erat pharetra. Morbi a justo id tortor consectetur convallis non sed ex. Sed volutpat, ex eget scelerisque lacinia, purus est finibus urna, nec venenatis lorem elit ac quam. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla id magna elit. Sed euismod, libero eu hendrerit auctor, mi urna eleifend velit, id suscipit ante sapien eget mi.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```